# React Native MapView without API key

Tags: react-native, expo, mapview

I want to use MapView from react-native-maps library in my react native expo project without going into Google API key pricing.
Is there any way to do that?
Currently, I am using UrlTile to display Openstreetmap maps but I am not sure if this the right way.

```
 <MapView
          region={location}
          rotateEnabled={false}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          style={styles.map}
          showsUserLocation
          mapType="none"
        >
          <UrlTile
            urlTemplate="https://a.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"

          />
          <Marker
            title="Home"
            coordinate={{
              latitude: location.latitude,
              longitude: location.longitude,
            }}
          />
        </MapView>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Lama https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71062115/react-native-maps-google-pricing This might help

Comment: If you use <MapView> without calling any Google API, then it's free.

Comment: You still need to add API Key in order to use <MapView> but it doesn't make any requests. These are the info I have right now based on someone else claim.
I didn't launch my app yet to confirm it.