# React Native Maps Google pricing

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-api, react-native-maps

As of 2022, does React Native Maps still free, or does go under any list of Google pricing?

I read this line on Reddit but it's 2 years ago

"Embedding Google Maps through `react-native-maps` does require an API key, but it is at no cost. Can confirm as I have an app at 100K users and haven't paid a dime for maps."

I am not sure if it is still the same.

This is my way of using it:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";
import MapView, {
  PROVIDER_GOOGLE,
  MAP_TYPES,
  PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
  UrlTile,
  Marker,
} from "react-native-maps";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  let location = {
    latitude: 30.259933,
    longitude: 31.412613,
    latitudeDelta: 0.009,
    longitudeDelta: 0.009,
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.myMap}>
        <MapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          showsUserLocation
          PROVIDER_GOOGLE
          MAP_TYPES="STANDARD"
        >
          <Marker
            title="Home"
            coordinate={{
              latitude: location.latitude,
              longitude: location.longitude,
            }}
          />
        </MapView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#ffd",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  myMap: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  map: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
});
```

I need some clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#dynamic-maps

[image: Mobile Native Dynamic Maps]

If you use a Map ID you will be charged. (This is new functionality)

[image: Dynamic Maps]

Comment: Thank you so much, one last thing, is my code considered map ID?

Comment: No, it is not using a map ID.